# change in free energy at natural state

Tags: thermodynamics

I am styding a book on thermoelasticity, here  free energy $f(e_{ij},T)$ is expended into taylor series in the vicinity of the natural state (when $e_{ij}=0$,$T=T_0$) and entropy s such that $s=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}$ where $e_{ij}$ are strain component and $T$ is temperature, and at natural  state it is assumed that s=0
and 
$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial T^2}=m$  at natural state.My question is why not $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial T^2} $ vanishes at natural state $(e_{ij}=0,T=T_0)$. please guide me... thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you expect the 2nd derivative of $f$ wrt $T$ to vanish near unstrained $e_{ij}=0$ equilibrium?

Comment: I think if entropy is zero at natural state then change in entropy wrt temperature should be 0 at natural state . am I right?

Comment: It is not that the "entropy" is zero in the natural state, after all the 3rd law says that entropy goes to zero as $T$ goes to zero but otheriwise positive, but rather in an unstrained state one has some *reference entropy* relative to which one measures a small variation by having a small strain. So the natural state is just that, no strain at some temperature with some supposedly known reference entropy relative to which the measurements are done.